# NSFetchRequest how to fetch different objects?

Tags: ios, nsfetchrequest

I want to fetch a result that doesn't have some same parameter.

like this.

Sample:

```
Obj1.title= @"1"
Obj2.title= @"3"
Obj3.title= @"3"
Obj4.title= @"3"
Obj5.title= @"4"
```

Result:

```
Obj1, Obj2, Obj5
```

Is it possible in NSFetchRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done by setting the returnDitinctProperties on the fetchRequest:

```
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
```

For this to work, you also need to set which properties need to be fetched:

```
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"title"];
```

Fore more details, see Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html

Comment: It was useful~ Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your `Objects.title` to an `NSArray` `myArray`, an then you can add the `myArray` to an `NSSet` to have an `NSSet` with unique titles.

```
NSSet *uniqueTitles = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];
```

Comment: I want to fetch the Obj, not the title.